# using ggplot and ggtern take string from variables in the dataframe to label arrows

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtern

using `ggplot2` with the extension `ggtern` I need to dynamically change the arrow labels based on the facet.

Starting off with

```r
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Tpoints, ~Lpoints, ~Rpoints,                    ~combo,
       0.4,      0.5,      0.1, "1_score-2_score-3_score",
       0.3,      0.2,      0.5, "1_score-2_score-3_score",
       0.5,      0.3,      0.2, "1_score-2_score-3_score",
       0.5,      0.4,      0.1, "1_score-2_score-3_score",
       0.4,      0.2,      0.4, "1_score-2_score-3_score",
       0.1,      0.9,        0, "1_score-2_score-4_score",
       0.5,      0.2,      0.3, "1_score-2_score-4_score",
       0.2,        0,      0.8, "1_score-2_score-4_score",
       0.5,      0.1,      0.4, "1_score-2_score-4_score",
       0.5,      0.3,      0.2, "1_score-2_score-4_score",
       0.4,      0.5,      0.1, "1_score-2_score-5_score",
       0.6,      0.3,      0.1, "1_score-2_score-5_score",
       0.2,      0.6,      0.2, "1_score-2_score-5_score",
         0,      0.5,      0.5, "1_score-2_score-5_score",
       0.5,      0.5,        0, "1_score-2_score-5_score",
       0.1,      0.9,        0, "1_score-3_score-4_score",
       0.5,      0.4,      0.1, "1_score-3_score-4_score",
       0.2,      0.2,      0.6, "1_score-3_score-4_score",
       0.1,      0.1,      0.8, "1_score-3_score-4_score",
       0.2,      0.1,      0.7, "1_score-3_score-4_score"
  ) |> 
  tidyr::separate(combo, into = c("A", "B", "C"), sep = "-", remove = FALSE)


PLOT <- ggtern::ggtern(data=df, ggplot2::aes(x = Lpoints, y = Tpoints, z = Rpoints))
PLOT +
  ggtern::theme_showarrows() +
  ggplot2::facet_wrap(~combo)
```

[Plain Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQrXE.png)

I need the arrow labels to be a string taken from the dataframe to get a plot like this

[Desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEZq4.png)

I have tried accessing information in the dataframe from `ggtern::Tlab(A)`. I tried using glue syntax `ggtern::Tlab("{A}")` and I have tried manually slamming the labels on by assigning to the plot object `PLOT$labels$Larrow <- c("1_score", "2_score")`